# Github actions workflow is stuck

Tags: github, github-actions

Hi my Workflow is stuck at the step: flow-target as the value being generated from the previous step is large and it seems it is unable to process it. It has been running for over 45 minutes (works fine for small data ).

```yaml
steps:
- name: converting vqltobase64
run: |
echo "get_value=$(base64 -w 0 metadata4.vql | cut -c 5- | iconv -f utf8 -t iso8859-5)" >> $GITHUB_ENV

  - name: flow-target
    run: curl --location 'https://10.xxx.x.xx:xxxx/test/loadFromVQL' --header 'Content-type:application/json' --header 'Authorization:Basic xxxxxxxxxxx' --data '{"name":"test_rev-007","description":"revision_creation","content":"'"${{ env.get_value }}"'"}' > at.json
    
  - name: get target id
    run:
       echo "get_revision_id= $(jq '.id' at.json)" >> $GITHUB_ENV
       
  - name: print revision id
    run : echo "${{env.get_revision_id }}"
    
  - name: deploy to target env
    run: curl -g --location 'https://10.xxx.x.xx:xxxx/deployments' --header 'Authorization:Basic xxxxxxxxxxx' --header 'Content-Type:application/json' --data '{"revisionIds":[${{env.get_revision_id}}],"environmentId":82,"description":"test"}'
```

Any suggestion is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think if the variable is more than 48kB you need to find an other solution, because is a limit for the single variable.

[Limits for variable.](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/variables#limits-for-configuration-variables)

Other solution should be store it in a file.

Comment: Im going for maven java project and run that from github actions. Hope that works